# Send Verification Email to Other Emails(Authentication Email) during Forgot Password in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to define custom Reset Password Policy to send verification email to Authentication Email address (not username). 
I am looking out for solutions but not able to find one.

Is it possible to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C supports basic customization of emails sent by Azure AD B2C through Azure AD's [Company Branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding). Customization of the template is not supported at this time, though you can vote for that ask in the Azure AD B2C Feedback forum: [Fully customizable verification emails](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails).

An alternative would be for you to avoid using the Reset Password policy at all and implement your own reset password mechanism which:

1. Generates its own codes
2. Sends its own emails
3. Has its own code redemption mechanism
4. [Uses the Graph API to reset the user's password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)