# How to send email code to secondary email (otherMails) in AzureAD B2C

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to send verification email code to secondary email address (otherMails or alternate email attribute in azure AAD) via azure B2C custom policy?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario in more detail, do you want the user to select the email from alternate email attribute or how will the user experience be? You can have b2c send the email to any email stored in any attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, customization of the email address is **not supported**. Azure AD B2C just supports basic customization of emails sent by Azure AD B2C.

You could vote for the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails). Please see this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317729/13308381).